# Entity Framework Treating Relationship as Columns

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-6

I'm attempting to create a DB-First model using EF 6.0 and I'm running into an issue. It appears that some of the relationships that should be interpreted navigation properties are instead being interpreted as simple columns. This is causing issues in the generated SQL saying "Invalid column name " However, it should be trying to join to the table name indicated in the column *using* the foreign key identifier. Here's the generated POCO to give an idea of what we're dealing with:

```
public partial class MyIntersection
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public string ContactId { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

The entity in question is a relationship between either an address and an account OR an address and a contact. However, these two states are mutually exclusive and only one relationship will ever be modeled in the data. It would look something like this:

[image: Sample intersection record]

The foreign keys have been created in the DB and appear to be functioning, but when I try to access the model, the SQL being generated looks like this:

```
{SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[AddressId] AS [AddressId], 
    [Extent1].[AccountId] AS [AccountId], 
    [Extent1].[ContactId] AS [ContactId], 
    [Extent1].[Accounts_AccountId] AS [Account_AccountId], 
    [Extent1].[Addresses_AddressId] AS [Addresses_AddressId], 
    [Extent1].[Contacts_ContactId] AS [Contacts_ContactId]
    FROM [dbo].[MyIntersections] AS [Extent1]}
```

I've made sure to add an extra column to avoid any issues with ambiguous relationships, but I'm still not seeing the behavior I'd expect. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue here. It turns out that I was mixing my EF approach and was causing problems for myself. I had done a DB first model, complete with an EDMX, but I was passing in my own connection (to easily switch between test, prod, etc). It turns out that doing so flipped me into code-first mode and I had to use fluent API to define my relationships. It looked something like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
        .HasMany(e => e.MyIntersections)
        .WithOptional(e => e.Contact)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.ContactId);

                modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
        .HasMany(e => e.MyIntersections)
        .WithOptional(e => e.Account)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.AccountId);

                modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
        .HasMany(e => e.MyIntersections)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Address)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.AddressId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Lesson learned!